# Get last 20 emails from Gmail (Java Android)

Tags: java, android, email, gmail-api

How can I get last 20 emails from gmail?

```
  ListMessagesResponse listMessagesResponse = mService.users().messages()
                    .list(user).setQ("from:----")
                    .execute();
```

Currently I am using this but it returns message IDs without any payload. I want to get full email with body. Can it be like get the latest email from specific sender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @trajchevska pointed out you can only get the basic details with your code. To get messages in full format you should call `mService.users().messages().get(user, messageId).execute()` for every message. Best way for this is to create a batch call. So if you want to get all the messages that match specified query you should do something like this.

```
final ListMessagesResponse response = mService.users().messages().list(user).setQ("from:----").execute();
final List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
while (response.getMessages() != null) {
    messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
    if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
        String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
        response = service.users().messages().list(user).setQ("from:----").setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

final List<Message> fullMessages = new ArrayList<>();
final JsonBatchCallback<Message> callback = new JsonBatchCallback<Message>() {
    public void onSuccess(Message message, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
        fullMessages.add(message);
    }

    public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
        // do what you want if error occurs
    }
};
BatchRequest batch = mService.batch();
for (Message message : messages) {
    mService.users().messages().get(user, message.getId()).setFormat("full").queue(batch, callback);
}

batch.execute();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The list function only returns the list of messages with basic details which is usually the id only. If you want to get the payload or other message details you need to iterate through all messages pulled with `list` and call the wanted function specifically on the selected object. I only have some basic knowledge in Java, but the logic would be something like this:

```
messages = listMessagesResponse.getMessages();
for (Message message : messages) {
  payload = message.getPayload();
  ...
}
```

Check their docs, they have some example that can be helpful.

[List Messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#examples)

[Get Concrete Message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#try-it)