# Download Emails from Gmail With Contents

Tags: java, rest, email, gmail-api

I want to download all emails with content. I got the REST API to get all emails but it returns only id and threadId, not other fields like labels, recipients, etc.

```
Get all email - https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/<email-id>/messages/
```

There is separate api to get all content but it works for single mail. So if I have 100 emails and I get content one by one it will be very slow.

```
Get content of email - https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/<email-id>/messages/<id>
```

Let me know what is the best way to list emails with contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Gmail API supports [Batch requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch)

This allows you to get all your messages in batch rather than 1 by 1.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38031702/11599789) is a sample on how to incorporate it in Java.